# How to troubleshoot 500 error on Azure with .NET Core 2.1 app?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

I've deployed a reasonably simple .NET Core 2.1 app to Azure (directly from Visual Studio 2017).  When I hit the website, it only returns error 500.

I dug into it looking at /LogFiles/DetailedErrors/ErrorPagexxxx.htm and among other things it says:

> IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
>
> IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
>
> IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
>
> The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
>
> The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

I am not sure where to go from here.  The application worked fine when it was .NET Core 1.x. Once I upgraded it from .NET Core 2, this happened.

What can I try to fix this issue?  And how do I get to the actual error that has occurred?

EDIT:

Thanks to Rafe's comment below, was able to run `dotnet MyApp.dll` directly from the Kudu console. This showed me the exact exception!

Comment: Does .NET Core 2.1 require the extension to be installed?  Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service

Comment: @BrendanGreen I have it marked as installing in the publish profile, but the problem is still happening.  The issue for me is how to get to the actual error that's occuring.  I did go through the troubleshooting steps, but nothing helped.

Comment: @BrendanGreen ...and the extension is installed.

Comment: Try deleting the site in azure and recreating the site in azure. Also, try running the application that you are deploying by running dotnet MyApp.dll and making sure that works. You need more details as to why it’s having an application issue. This might help. Also consider testing using a self contained application. Also try installing the asp.net core extension on the azure app service

Comment: @joey I ended doing what you suggested - just getting rid of the entire site and recreating it.  It worked!  Unfortunately I have no idea what went wrong or how to prevent it in the future.

Comment: What worked for me was logging into kudu and running 'dotnet MyApp.dll' which then showed the actual exception that was being thrown in my Startup.cs file.